# removing specific rows from pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pd.DataFrame which has students' exam performance metrics in each row. Each student has a unique ID, and each student has a unique row for the questions they solved on the exam. For example, student with ID "a1a1" has attempted two questions whereas student with ID "w2e3" has attempted only one question. (sample df)

[image]

I want to find the students who have attempted to solve less than 3 questions and remove the rows associated with them from the data-frame. How can I do this with pd.DataFrame methods?

Comment: problemID is just a unique identification number for each problem. Each row represents a question solved by the student, so if a question solved three questions, he/she has three rows(entries) in this data frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `value_counts()` on `studentID`

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'studentID':['a','a','a','b','b','b', 'c'],
                   'problemID':[1,2,3,1,2,3,1]})
print(df)
tmp = df['studentID'].value_counts()
tmp = tmp[tmp >= 3]
new_df = df[df['studentID'].isin(tmp.index)]
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
  studentID  problemID
0         a          1
1         a          2
2         a          3
3         b          1
4         b          2
5         b          3
6         c          1

  studentID  problemID
0         a          1
1         a          2
2         a          3
3         b          1
4         b          2
5         b          3
```

Comment: this just returns to a list, how can I remove those entries from my original data frame

Comment: AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'index'

Comment: Sorry, now it should work, i was a bit hasty

Comment: I just don't understand why ```.index``` is needed on the last line

Comment: Becase the `tmp` Series has name of students as index and number of solved problems as values.